# If a $MC$ is irreducible and aperiodic, for every node pair $(i, j)$, there exists $N(i, j)$ such that $P^{n_{ij}} > 0$ whenever $n\geq N(i, j).$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

How can I go about proving the following?

If a $MC$ is irreducible and aperiodic, for every node pair $(i, j)$, there exists $N(i, j)$ such that $P^{n_{ij}} > 0$ whenever $n \geq N(i, j).$

Answer (score 1):

See Proposition 1.7 on page 8 of *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Peres, and Wilmer.

> If $P$ is aperiodic and irreducible, then there is an integer $r$ such that $P^r(x,y) > 0$ for all $x,y ∈ \Omega$.

The text is available for free online (on [this site](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) for instance). The result is presented and proved in a straightforward fashion.  I suggest that you read through the proof and make a new question post about any questions you have, if you have any.